# how to order data by distance in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

i want to sort by Json data by distance my shot
controller

```
$scope.distancia = function($latitudeTo, $longitudeTo) {
  $latFrom = deg2rad($scope.position.coords.latitude);
  $lonFrom = deg2rad($scope.position.coords.longitude);
  $latTo = deg2rad($latitudeTo);
  $lonTo = deg2rad($longitudeTo);
  console.log($latitudeTo);
  $latDelta = $latTo - $latFrom;
  $lonDelta = $lonTo - $lonFrom;

  $angle = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Math.sin($latDelta / 2), 2) +
    Math.cos($latFrom) * Math.cos($latTo) * Math.pow(Math.sin($lonDelta / 2), 2)));
  return $angle * 6371;
}
```

and in html

```
<div class="row text-center" ng-controller="MainController">
<div ng-repeat="product in products.Products | orderBy:'-distancia(location.coordinates[0],location.coordinates[1])'" class="col-sm-3">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <p><strong>{$ distancia(product.location.coordinates[0],product.location.coordinates[1]) $}</strong></p>
    <img ng-src="{$ product.picture $}" alt="{$ product.name $}">
    {% if request.session.authenticate %}
    <button type="button" name="button" ng-click="like($index)" class="like-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
    <button type="button" name="button" ng-click="deslike($index)" class="deslike-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
    {% endif %}

  </div>
</div>
```

but don't sorted my data o don't know why

Comment: you forgot "product" in orderBy function

Comment: same thing don't sorted

Comment: `orderBy` takes the name of the field that you want to order data by (e.g. `orderBy: 'location'`, assuming there's `product.location`). But you're passing it a string (which contains a function call) that's not there in the `product`, so it won't work... what exactly are you trying to order them by?

Comment: @OmarEinea thank you for your explain
i want to display the list of products sorted by distance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to order the data by a value that's not in the data itself, it's rather calculated from it (which is distance). But for `orderBy` to work, the field that you want to order by has to be in the data. The best method I can think of for your case is to calculate and store the distance in your data once you fetch it directly.

I'll assume that you're loading the data through an `$http` request, something like this:

```
$http.get("PRODUCTS_LINK").then(function(response) {
    $scope.products = response.data;
});
```

You could loop through the data right there and calculate the distance for each product:

```
$http.get("PRODUCTS_LINK").then(function(response) {
    $scope.products = response.data;

    angular.forEach($scope.products, function(product) {
        product.distance = $scope.distancia(product.location.coordinates[0], product.location.coordinates[1]);
    });
});
```

Once this is, all your `$scope.products` will have `distance` variable in them which then you can order them by. Like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products | orderBy:'-distance'" class="col-sm-3">
```

Though, what I see from the HTML you posted in your question is that you're using `jinja2` server-side templating to load the data. If that's the case, you probably should pick **one** side (server or client) to do data loading, ordering and filtering. Doing it through both is quite a mess.